# PostgreSQL dump/restore

Tags: postgresql, dump, database-restore, database-dump

I don't want to `Dump` the **entire table** but only **certain records in a table** in my dump file and later `restore` the same.
P.S.: I want to do the same for more than **1 table in my database** but dump it in a single file.
Is this possible? If yes then how do i go about it?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pondlife mentioned in his answer had to use `COPY` command but did not solve my Problem of getting all the dump data into a single file.
So from the idea given by [Craig Ringer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500142/postgresql-dump-temp-table) made individual files for each table and got all
the files compressed into a single archive file.
For restore uncompressed the archive to generate individual files later used them to restore the Tables.

Had to answer my own question so it might help somebody.

Answer (score 2):

The [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html) command?

Answer (score 2):

Should be possible using [Jailer](http://jailer.sf.net).

Comment: @ZigArt but I am not using java.

Answer (score 1):

create temp_tables from *sqlquery*

*sqlquery* can be formed as projection like 'select *columns* from *table*'

then use pg_dump to dump all temporary tables using --table option.
[pgadmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) can help dumping tables in a single file here.

Restore all temp tables from pgadmin and run INSERT query on main table.

Comment: Yes.
pg_dump --host hostname --port portno --username "username" --format custom --verbose --file "filename" --table "schema.temp_table" "dbname"

Comment: have u tried it?
because I error saying **No matching Table were found**

Comment: Check if tablename is given as schemaname.tablename in pg_dump args